# Call .ps1 from cmd file give the error: : The term '.\setup.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Tags: powershell

Via VS 2017 calling `Setup.cmd` which contains:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\setup.ps1 "%*"
```

The file is called, and this error appear:

```
Active code page: 65001
.\setup.ps1 : The term '.\setup.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a  cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\setup.ps1 -SkipDbInstall:0 -SkipPandoSupportInstall:0 -SkipSearchServiceInstal ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\setup.ps1:String) [], Command     NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

`setup.ps1` exist in the same level like `setup.cmd`.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Sometimes, .cmd files execute from the temp directory instead of the location they reside. Try to echo out the location and see if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that `windows environment variable` was pointing to 2 msbuild file locations on the file system, so when I ran the command `msbuild` in cmd - the wrong msbuild was called.

Deleting the wrong one and leaving the good one, in the `windows environment variable` - did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your working directory is not what you think it is. You can verify that by adding a line `echo %CD%` to the batch file.

To change the working directory to the folder in which the scripts reside add a line `cd /d "%~dp0"`. You also need to remove the quotes from `%*`, otherwise all arguments to your batch script will be passed as a single string argument to the PowerShell script. And I'd recommend using the parameter `-File` with `powershell.exe`, so that you'll get a proper exit code from the PowerShell script (if it returns one).

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
chcp 65001 >nul
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File .\setup.ps1 %*
```

If the PowerShell script doesn't care about the working directory you could also run it with the full path instead of changing the directory:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "%~dp0setup.ps1" %*
```

Comment: tried the 1st example and getting this: `setup.ps1 : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 
'SkipDbInstall'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type 
"System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, 
such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [setup.ps1], ParentContainsErro 
   rRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,setup.ps1
`

Comment: That is a problem with the parameter handling of your PowerShell script. Basically, when invoking PowerShell scripts from outside PowerShell all arguments are strings. That's a different question, though, and should be posted as such.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to change the directory by yourself:

```
PowerShell -Command "cd \scripts; .\setup.ps1"
```